# Insert a field with PREG_REPLACE – strange behaviour

Tags: functions, advanced-custom-fields, single, customization

I'm trying to insert a custom field (from the Advanced Custom Fields plugin), and I need to place it within a div which I'm wrapping around an img, right before the img-tag.

So basically this is the result I want (I use `the_field('description')` here to make it cleaner):

```
<div class="the-content">
    <div class="owl-wrapper">
        <div class="owl-item">
            [ the content from the_field() ]
            <img src"http://imagesource">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this is what happens:

```
<div class="the-content">
    [ the content from the_field() ]
    <div class="owl-wrapper">
        <div class="owl-item">
            <img src"http://imagesource">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I.e. content from the field gets inserted at the top instead of in the div I place it. Isn't it rather strange?

Here's my code:

```
function wrapImagesInDiv($content) {
    if ( in_category( 'projects' ) ) {
        $pattern = '/(<img[^>]*class=\"([^>]*?)\"[^>]*>)/i';
        $replacement = '
        <div class="owl-wrapper">
            <div class="owl-item $2">
                '.the_field('description').'
                $1
            </div>
        </div>';
        $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wrapImagesInDiv');
```

Comment: I don't know about ACF but in Wordpress land, the functions named `the_*()` echoes content, so you can not use them to set the value of another var. Maybe `the_field` function actually echoes some content instead of return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `get_field` function here instead of `the_field`.

```
function wrapImagesInDiv($content) {
    if ( in_category( 'projects' ) ) {
        $pattern = '/(<img[^>]*class=\"([^>]*?)\"[^>]*>)/i';
        $replacement = '
        <div class="owl-wrapper">
            <div class="owl-item $2">
                '.get_field('description').'
                $1
            </div>
        </div>';
        $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wrapImagesInDiv');
```

Function `get_field` returns the value but `the_field` prints the value.

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick :)